# with bootstrap, adding position absolute changes width of element

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an unusual responsive layout I need to do in CSS only. I have it all working except that for tablet view (768px - 992px) box `A` (the red one) has the wrong width. This happens when I apply position absolute, which I am doing in order to take it out of the flow, and allow the rest of the elements to move into place.

```css
.red {
  height: 150px;
  background-color: red;
}
.green {
  height: 150px;
  background-color: green;
}
.blue {
  height: 150px;
  background-color: blue;
}
.yellow {
  height: 150px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 992px) {
  /* `.row` added for specificity's sake */
  .row .red {
    position: absolute;
    top: 150px;
    z-index: 1000;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 992px){
  .items {
    height: 50px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-4 col-md-4 red">A</div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-12 col-md-8 green items">B</div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4 col-md-offset-0 col-md-8 blue items">C</div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-4 col-md-8 yellow items">D</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I adjust this so that box `A` has the same size as `C` and `D` on tablet view?

(I am open to completely re-thinking the way the layout is achieved)

### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/billymoon/e64qLhp1/1/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can be fixed by adding `position: relative` to that wrapping `row` div..

Comment: Previousley it may be 33.333% of the body width.

Comment: Ah - so adding any kind of position to the .row element should work, so that it becomes the parent for the absolutely positioned div. Nice - thanks.